# Save email as email rather than attachement

Tags: email, email2case, email2salesforce

if I send an email to Salesforce, the record is saved as an Activity (goes into my Unresolved Items and I then choose what object to attach it to), whereas if I use emailtocase the record is saved as an email attached to a new case. Do I need to enable Enhanced Email option so that the record would be saved as email for Email to Salesforce?

Comment: Are looking for some specific format like `.msg` extension.

Comment: ?? No. I'm talking about the two different objects: EmailMessage and Activity, With Enhanced... the email gets saved as the EmailMessage object, whereas in the old school it gets saved as Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even with Email to Case enabled, you'll want to enable Enhanced Email. Per [Considerations for Setting Up Enhanced Email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_enhanced_email_considerations.htm&type=0):

> If you use Email-to-Case, you can already use custom fields, customized layouts, workflow rules, and triggers with emails without enabling Enhanced Email. Plus, you already use the EmailMessage object to store emails associated with cases. If you want to be able to relate EmailMessage records to other objects (besides cases), then we recommend that you enable Enhanced Email.

Also see KB 000239922 [Enhanced email and the Email Message object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000239922&language=en_US&type=1):

> The Email Message record respects established mail paradigms for compliance.  The email record in Salesforce has to be a non-editable, accurate representation of the mail the end user receives.  Unlike the Task object which is editable, Email Messages cannot be edited through the User Interface or the API.